# How to maintain date value in register form once is submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, date, slim

We are currently doing a project with php with slim where I have to do a register form.
One of the inputs of the form is the birthday which is date type.
When I submit the register, I want to display the errors of the inputs and maintain the information entered by the user.
I have managed to do it in the inputs with text and password type, however, for the date type I can't find a way to maintain the information.

This is .twig file:

```
  <input type="password"
           name="repeat_password"
           placeholder="repeat password"
           value="{% if formData.repeat_password %}{{ formData.repeat_password }}{% endif %}">
    {% if formErrors.repeat_password %}
        <p style="color: red;">{{ formErrors.repeat_password }}</p>
    {% endif %}


    <input type="date"
           name="birthday"
           placeholder="birthday"
           value="{% if formData.birthday %}{{ localStorage.setItem(formData.birthday,) }}{% endif %}">
    {% if formErrors.birthday %}
        <p style="color: red;">{{ formErrors.birthday }}</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you would have to get the form data from the request, validate it and pass it to the Twig render method as an array.